# When one option set to True all others set to False (BooleanField)

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have this form:

```
forms.py

class OptionForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}), max_length=100, label='Option Name')
    default = forms.BooleanField(label='Default', required=False)
```

So I can add a new option or edit one that already exist with this two views

```
views.py

def new_opt(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        fnewopt = OptionForm(request.POST)
        if fnewopt.is_valid():
            model = OptionModel()
            model.name = fnewopt.cleaned_data.get('name')
            model.default = fnewopt.cleaned_data.get('default')
            model.save()

def edit_opt(request, id_opt):
    opt = OptionModel.objects.get(id=id_opt)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        feditopt = OptionForm(request.POST)
        if feditopt.is_valid():
            model = opt
            model.name = feditopt.cleaned_data.get('name')
            model.default = feditopt.cleaned_data.get('default')
            modelo.save()
```

But I need that **when a user choose one option as default no matter if is new or one that already exist all others options set default to `False`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by customizing your model's `save()` method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    if self.default:
        # At this point self.pk will exist whether
        # this was a new or updated instance.
        # Using update() allows this to run in a single query
        # (plus the query for super().save(), of course).
        OptionModel.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk).update(default=False)
```

A few other notes:

- You should wrap your `save()` method in an atomic transaction.
- This will do the extra `update()` every time the option is saved, not just the first time. To avoid that you'd have to detect when the value was *changed* to `True`. There are third-party packages to allow you to do that, but it's probably not worth the bother.
- This question and answer doesn't address the validation issue—what if another `OptionModel` already has `default=True`?

Comment: Right now I solve it but using the views, do you know wich is better, custom the `save()` method or do it in the views?

Comment: @M.Gar: For something like this—where you're trying to enforce a data constraint—you're better off putting it in the model (i.e. `save()`) rather than the view. For one thing, objects can be created in places other than your view (admin, the shell, etc.). For another, it makes testing easier.

Answer (score 1):

If your new option has `default=True`, set all existing options' `default=false` then set your new option `default = true`. I'm not sure where your options go when they get saved. You might have a better time finding out which option is true and just setting that false.